# Using C++ generic programming to do runtime call of func(x,y) for all permutations of x and y types

Tags: c++, c++11

```
env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapInstance, put, _, _)
```

I want to call this function with all the possible permutations of `std::string`, `int`, `double` on the underscores. For example:

```
env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapInstance, put, myString, myInt)
env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapInstance, put, myInt, myDouble)
env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapInstance, put, myInt, myInt)
//...
```

Of course I can do this with nested ifs but I'd be reusing the same code on lots of places. Ideally I'd like a way to receive a `std::map<JavaObject, JavaObject> myMap` and then for each pair on the map, do the following:

```
for (auto pair : myMap)
    if (pair.first.type == JavaObject::String && pair.second.type == JavaObject::Integer)
        env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapInstance, put, pair.first.getString(), pair.second.getInt()) 
    //OR
    if (pair.first.type == JavaObject::Integer && pair.second.type == JavaObject::Integer)
        env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapInstance, put, pair.first.getInt(), pair.second.getInt()) //
    //OR
    if (pair.first.type == JavaObject::Double && pair.second.type == JavaObject::String)
        env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapInstance, put, pair.first.getDouble(), pair.second.getString()) 
    //...
```

as you can see, I need a way to efficiently be able to call each permutation `env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapInstance, put, _, _)` for every possible permutation of `JavaObject, JavaObject` received (`JavaObject` is just a class that can hold `string`, `int`, `double` and possibly more in the future)

The first thing I thought was to create a templated function:

```
template<typename T, typename V>
void myCallobjectMethod(env, jobject instance, jmethodID method, T obj1, V obj2)
```

But I still have to read `JavaObject.type` for the first item and then inside this if, do another if for the second part, just to call my templated function, so I'm still with the same problem.

I thought of another way, in pseudocode:

```
using namespace std::placeholders; 
for (auto pair : myMap)
    auto bind1 = std::bind(env->CallObjectMethod, hashMapInstance, put, _3, _4); //binds the hashMapInstance and put
    auto bind2 = std::bind(bind1, pair.first, _2); //binds the first object
    auto bind3 = std::bind(bin2, pair.second); //binds the second object
bind3(); //now I can call bind3 to execute the call
```

but it's not that simple, I don't even know what's happening to the types of things here.

Comment: I don't see any C++ shortcut that makes C++ itself do it for you. No matter how you look at it, you will have to come up with a mapping between a `JavaObject` enumeration and the corresponding getter. Then you will have to generate all possible permutation of the two parameters, and a separate, individual function call. C++ simply does not work in any other way. Yes, I sort of can see a template-based monstrosity that will end up generating each function call, but I doubt that it would save much time. I would consider redesigning things here, maybe use `std::variant` in some cleaner way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik just to be clear, I don't want to call all permutations, I want to call the permutation based on the `JavaObject, JavaObject` pair I received. That's what youo said isn't possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JavaObject` is a sum type, so it should have a `visit` function:

```
template<class F> auto visit(F&& f, JavaObject const& o) {
    switch (o.type) {
        case JavaObject::String : return f(o.getString());
        case JavaObject::Integer : return f(o.getInt());
        case JavaObject::Double : return f(o.getDouble());
    }
}
```

Any unary `visit` function can be composed with itself to operate on 2 arguments:

```
template<class F> auto visit(F&& f, JavaObject const& o1, JavaObject const& o2) {
    return visit([&](auto const& x1) {
        return visit([&](auto const& x2) {
            return f(x1, x2); }, o2); }, o1);
}
```

Now you can write:

```
visit([&](auto const& x1, auto const& x2) {
    env->CallObjectMethod(hashMapInstance, put, x1, x2);
}, pair.first, pair.second);
```

Extending `visit` to arbitrary arity is left as an exercise for the reader (Hint: use recursion).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ecatmur's answer, I am going to give some hint on how to do the permutation:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

void test(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g) {
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << " " << e << " " << f << " " << g << std::endl;
}

template <typename ReturnT, typename T, typename U, typename ... TRestArgs>
auto easy_bind(std::function<ReturnT(T, TRestArgs...)> func, U&& arg) -> std::function<ReturnT(TRestArgs...)> {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, ReturnT>) {
        return [=](TRestArgs... args) { func(arg, args...); };
    }
    else {
        return [=](TRestArgs... args) { return func(arg, args...); };
    }
}

template <typename CallableT, typename ... TArgs, std::size_t ... SeqLeft, std::size_t ... SeqRight>
void permute_call_impl(CallableT func, std::tuple<TArgs...> args, std::index_sequence<SeqLeft...>, std::index_sequence<SeqRight...>);

template <typename CallableT, typename ... TArgs, std::size_t ... Seq>
void permute_call_splitter(CallableT func, std::tuple<TArgs...> args, std::index_sequence<Seq...>);

template <typename CallableT, typename ... TArgs, std::size_t ... SeqLeft, std::size_t ... SeqRight>
void permute_call_impl(CallableT func, std::tuple<TArgs...> args, std::index_sequence<SeqLeft...>, std::index_sequence<SeqRight...>) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(SeqLeft) + sizeof...(SeqRight) == 0u) {
        func();
    }
    else {
        permute_call_splitter(func,
            std::make_tuple(std::get<SeqLeft>(args)..., std::get<SeqRight + sizeof...(SeqLeft) + 1>(args)...),
            std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(SeqLeft) + sizeof...(SeqRight)>{}
        );
    }
}

template <typename CallableT, typename ... TArgs, std::size_t ... Seq>
void permute_call_splitter(CallableT func, std::tuple<TArgs...> args, std::index_sequence<Seq...>) {
    constexpr auto size = sizeof...(Seq);
    (permute_call_impl(easy_bind(func, std::get<Seq>(args)),
        args,
        std::make_index_sequence<Seq>{},
        std::make_index_sequence<size - 1u - Seq>{}
    ), ...);
}

template <typename CallableT, typename ... TArgs>
void permute_call(CallableT func, TArgs... args) {
    permute_call_splitter(func, std::make_tuple(args...), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(TArgs)>{});
}

int main() {
    std::function func = test;
    permute_call(func, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

So basically you have a `std::index_sequence`, you iterate on every index, remove the element, merge the rest two parts, and pass it to the next level of recursion.

---

I did not take care of reference forwarding in this example, for now. But it would gives you a rough idea about how things should work.

[Live Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/f734vqTgfyapoYMD)